# unity .. a logic loop for checking 12 position

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I have this code:

```
if(car.position == a1.position)
  {
    car.speed = 0;
    a1 = 1;
   if(cooldow == 0){
        car.taget.position = targetHere.position
        car.speed = 5;
        a1 = 0;
        Destroy(obj, 5)
       }
  }
```

the first condition [if(car.position == a1.position)] i will repeat it more than 10 time i mean i will check if (car.position) will be the same like **a2.position** then a**3.position** then **a4.position** then **a5.position** then **a6.position** then **b1.position** then **b2.position** then **b3.position** then **b4.position** then **b5.position** then **b6.position** .... twelve times ... and i couldn't find the logic to put it in a (***For***) loop.

Any Idea How To Do It!!! TY

Comment: Hint: stick with `==` and don't use `.Equals`! [this is why](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Equals.html) - Maybe better: Use `Abs(pos1 - pos1) < 0.1f`, or consider using colliders marked as triggers for the 12 positions - avoiding your programming problem completely.

Comment: @KYL3R misread your comment I thought you were telling him to go with `.Equals` anyways instead of using < 0.1f he can also use `Mathf.Approximately`.  PS pos1-pos1 would be 0.

Comment: Yes, wanted to add Appox too, good point! But for a Vector3 it's easier to use `==` because you'd have to write that 3 times otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming a1 is a transform since you are accessing the position variable of it.  I am also assuming you are assigning these gameobjects individually in the inspector.

I would do the follow:

```
// Make sure to put all your a objects in this list in the inspector
public List<Transform> myABCObjects; 

void CheckPositions()
{
    // This foreach loop, will loop through your list of transforms, so your a b c 
    // objects would be added to this list via the inspector, or through whatver
    // code you are using to set them.
    foreach(Transform a in myABCObjects)
    {
        // Not to sure if you can do an == on a vector3, but I wouldn't want to
        // considering the data members are float, and can cause floating point error
        // Because of this I am getting the distance to the location, and using
        // Mathf.Approximately to check if the distance is close to 0f.
        if(Mathf.Approximately(car.position.distance(a.position), 0f))
        {
            // Your logic here if location is the same...
            // so if you are trying to remove say a1
            // add this object to a list, to be removed after the loop
            // then continue on.
        }
    }

    // if you are removing an object, check the list size, then loop through it to remove the objects from your original list...
}
```

Example using a for loop instead of a foreach:

```
// Make sure to put all your a objects in this list in the inspector
public List<Transform> myABCObjects; 

void CheckPositions()
{
    // This for loop, will loop through indices 0 - myABCObjects.count - 1, so your a b c 
    // objects would be added to this list via the inspector, or through whatver
    // code you are using to set them.
    for(int i = 0; i < myABCObjects.count; ++i)
    {
        // Not to sure if you can do an == on a vector3, but I wouldn't want to
        // considering the data members are float, and can cause floating point error
        // Because of this I am getting the distance to the location, and using
        // Mathf.Approximately to check if the distance is close to 0f.
        if(Mathf.Approximately(car.position.distance(myABCObjects[i].position), 0f))
        {
             // Your logic here if location is the same...

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you might also want to add a `break;` in case you have a match in order to only execute the code for the first encountered match like in `if - else if`

Comment: @derHugo yes that is a possibility depending on exactly what he is doing, if he is going through waypoints that is an excellent suggestion, if he is checking procedurally placed fueld cans he might not want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If [a1..a6] and [b1..b6] have the same type, than try to do so:

```
var list = new List<TypeOfa1> {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6};             

foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (car.position == item.position)
    {
        car.speed = 0;
        item = 1;
        if (cooldow == 0)
        {
            car.taget.position = targetHere.position;
            car.speed = 5;
            item = 0;
            Destroy(obj, 5);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a collection of your variables then run a foreach through them.

```
List<CarType> collection = new List<CarType> {a1, b1, a2, b2 ...};
foreach (CarType c in collection)
{
    // do stuff
}
```